# Why can't I call self.save in Rails 3.0.7?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

When calling a method in my model I would like to update a field called "started". This seems straightforward, but:

This breaks:

```
has_many :terra_players, :dependent => :destroy

serialize :territory_owners

class SomeGame < ActiveRecord::Base

    
  def startGame
    self.territory_owners = []
    
    self.terra_players.each do |i|
      i.update_attributes(:my_turn => true, :army_pool => 35)
    end
    
    #give each player maxterritory number of territories
   
    
    max_territories = 42 / self.terra_players.length 
    spare_territories = 42 % self.terra_players.length 
    
    for i in (0..42-spare_territories-1) #bleh
      # pick a random player, make sure they still need territories
      player = nil
      while (true) do
        player = self.terra_players.sample
        if player.num_territories < max_territories
          break
        end
      end
      self.territory_owners.push([player, 1]) #hash instead maybe?
      # make sure player gets updated too
      player.num_territories += 1
      player.save
    end
    
    
    if spare_territories != 0
      j = 0
      for k in (i+1..42-1)
        player = self.terra_players[j]
        j += 1
        self.territory_owners.push([player, 1]) #hash instead maybe?
        
        player.num_territories += 1
        player.save
      end
    end
    self.update_attribute(:started, true)
    self.save
  end
```

I get:

> ArgumentError in TerraPlayersController#create
>
> wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)

On the `self.update_attribute(:started, true)` line.

Yet this seems to work:

```
class SomeGame < ActiveRecord::Base

  def startGame

        ...

    myself = TerraGame.find(self.id)
    myself.update_attribute(:started, true)
    myself.save
  end
```

Why does the second one work but not the first? Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. My serialized attribute needs to be encoded and decoded during saving/using.

Because of this, `self`'s save was screwing up.

As Eris said, the second way only worked because I didn't save the erroneous changes to `self`

Answer (score 2):

The [`update_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) function saves the update to the database (without validations) so it doesn't make much sense to call `update_attribute` AND `save` the way you are doing.

However I still don't understand why you are getting that error.  Could you try this instead?

```
def start
    self.started = true
    self.save
end
```

Comment: Ugh, that's something I actually knew but forgot. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though the error remains. I added the full code for `startGame`, I'm wondering if the serialized territory_owners is the real problem.

Comment: Did you try replacing `update_attribute(:started,true)` with `self.started = true`?  Are you sure you are still getting the same error because that would be odd.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just gonna paste here what I said to you already.

> 22:55 the fact that re-finding the object and saving it seems to imply to me that the error is coming from something you've done to the object in the startGame method
>   22:55 myself isn't actually the same object in Ruby; it is a new instance initialised from the same data
>   22:55 but it doesn't have any of the changes you've made in the method because they weren't saved
>   22:55 so, I actually do know why that works

So, that much we know. You're gonna need to divulge more of the startGame method to identify the real problem, I think.